# Using aggregate summed data as part of a tablix title row

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008

I would like to use a summed value from a details group as part of the header of a tablix. Say I have 12 records contained in the report, I would like the summed figure (ie. 12) to be included as part of the Header title - some thing like 'This Report contains 12 records that match your criteria'. I can get the SUM no problem, but getting it up to the top of the report is proving impossible. Can you refer to the text box that contains the SUM somehow?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have no experience of Tablix and little experiance of SQL Reporting.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with the following steps:

1. Add a textbox to your header
2. Add an expression to the textbox (I think that you can do this by right-clicking
3. Fill in the expression as `=CountRows("<dataset name>")`, using the appropriate dataset name

I don't have RS running at the moment. If I'm off or this doesn't work, then please post and I'll make any necessary corrections

Comment: Thanks Tom
I'll give it a whirl and let you know how I get on.

Comment: I added the = to CountRows for completeness sake, =CountRows("").  Good answer!